# MATLAB change color in patch to custom

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this code:

```
patch([x3 fliplr(x4)], [y3 fliplr(y4)], 'g' 'EdgeColor','g')
```

How can I specify my color instead of 'g'?

I tried this:

```
patch([x3 fliplr(x4)], [y3 fliplr(y4)], 'Color', [1 1 1], 'EdgeColor','g')
```

But I get an error. Anyone see any obvios mistakes?

Comment: Someone else posted a comment and deleted it with what I think is the right answer. `'Color'` is not a name/value variable, so just remove `'Color',`.

Comment: Yea I was double checking that. If you update the live editor https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html to run with the rgb it works. No label needed

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. If I change it to [1 1 1] or any code, my graph is no longer filled in. The patch fills the area between two radial limits. When I do what you suggested, the area is not filled.

Comment: Well [1,1,1] is white. If you change it to [1,1,0] you get yellow.

Comment: Is there a page that I can find all the colors?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html is the reference on patch. Search for RGB

Answer (score 0):

The line should read:

```
patch([x3 fliplr(x4)], [y3 fliplr(y4)], [1 1 1], 'EdgeColor','g')
```

You do not need to define the label. This will fill white as the RGB triplet [1,1,1], yellow is [1,1,0]. If you want other colors you can check out the colorspec provided by Matlab: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html

You can also view more values by typeing `colormapeditor` and hovering over the color bar to get RGB. There are different colormaps that you can use and you can get the current colors defined by typing `colormap` in the matlab prompt.  For more info on color maps check out: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#buq1hym